# Ruby on Rails error: superclass mismatch for class StringIO (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting an error while creating a ruby on rails project. In command, I created a new project by typing `rails new club`, then `bundle`. Now, when I try to create my models and controllers by typing and entering `rails g resource Club name`, I get this error: `superclass mismatch for class StringIO (TypeError)`.

```
gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:
in `require': superclass mismatch for class StringIO (TypeError)
```

I don't even has a class named `StringIO`, so I'm not sure where it came from.

- ruby version: 2.6.8
- rails: 6.1.4.1

Comment: please add your ruby and rails versions and paste in the relevant bit of the stack trace.

Comment: I am getting this too on ruby 2.7.4, rails 6.1.4.1 after updating all my gems.

gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': superclass mismatch for class StringIO (TypeError)

Comment: Ruby on rails version: 2.6.8

Comment: My rails version is 6.1.4.1

Comment: Comments are not permanent -- edit the question please.

Comment: Try commenting out `bootsnap` from your `Gemfile`. It's optional. Also, always use `bundle exec rails` instead of just `rails`.

Comment: Same exact stack trace in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69888207/active-admin-wont-install-superclass-mismatch-for-class-stringio-typeerror No answer there, though

Comment: I tried commenting out `bootsnap`, but got this error: `cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)`

Comment: I removed bootsnap as well, and I removed the require 'bootsnap/setup' from boot.rb, and I still get the error minus all the bootsnap in the stacktrace. It seems anything requiring 'stringio' is a problem.

Comment: @JaredBeck I found these two as well, all from this month with no resolution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902775/getting-error-trying-to-start-ruby-on-rails
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69794498/command-rails-server-not-working-or-rails-server-command-not-working

Comment: I am finding the same, no `Rails`.  Just `Ruby 2.7.2`, `2.7.3`, `2.7.4`.  I thought it was `Passenger`.  https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2395

Answer (score 19):

Try reverting to an earlier version of StringIO

```
gem install stringio -v 0.1.4

gem uninstall stringio # remove 3.0.0 and 3.0.1
```

Comment: Even without installing a specific version I was able to fix this issue by simply running `gem uninstall stringio` to remove all non-default versions.

Comment: removal without the addition worked for me too

Answer (score 9):

As others have said on @jason-lee answer, for many people, this can be fixed  just by uninstalling the existing `stringio` then running `bundle install` again.

```bash
    gem uninstall stringio
    bundle
```

Answer (score 6):

None of the above answers worked for me. What happened for me is that I added `gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.67.2', require: false` to `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install`.

This version of `rubocop` seems to have installed `psych` as a dependency and then `psych` has a dependency on `stringio` and I, correct me if I'm wrong, that must be conflicting with whatever `stringio` version is being used by `bootsnap`.

Anyway, to solve it I just deleted the `rubocop` line I added to `Gemfile` and added `gem 'rubocop', require: false` (which installed the latest rubocop version) then ran `bundle install` again.

Comment: THe funny thing is that I just removed stringio gem and things started to work. Not sure it had anything to do with psych. It was crazy but your posts helped me going.

Answer (score 3):

I started getting this error after updating my gems. I tried uninstalling ruby and all my gems, updating rvm, but for me the solution appeared to be updating rubygems.

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: This worked on ruby 2.6.10 for me, YMMV

Comment: Works well on ruby 2.7.2p137

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

My Error was: The application encountered the following error: superclass mismatch for class StringIO (TypeError)

The problem was caused by this issue
https://www.redmine.org/issues/35435

It might help you. I also removed all gems related to  #gem 'sdoc'
It seams like by default sdoc call internally gem 'psych', which is the gem uses the StringIO and both have different version you can check the difference in your GemFile.Lock to see difference between your 2 versions.

Answer (score 0):

The error was gone when I bumped Ruby version to 3.0.4 from 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

RVM on Ubuntu (path related issue):

Exit all terminals

```
exit
```

Then start a new terminal, then:

```
rvm use [your version]
bundle install
rails c
```